# Find all the tags in Rspec before running the tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, reverse-engineering

I am using rspec(3.5) to run my tests and building a CLI with it. Currently considering rake. In my CLI, I would like it to be able to find all of the tags available in my spec folders and provide it as an option to run as tests BEFORE RUNNING THE RSPEC.

I've been prying through spec_helper and haven't been able to find the tag information. My understanding is, rspec CLI itself accepts all of the tags as input, it then goes through all of the files to see if each of them matches the tags, if it does, rspec will run them.

I would like to reverse this workflow -

1. Find all the tags in my spec folder.
2. Provide it as an option in my rake cli.
3. Allow the user to choose the tag and run it.

Right now I'm stuck at step 1, finding all the tags.
Suppose, how do I scan through all the spec folders without running the test, and expose the tags somewhere?

Sample Excerpt from my code. The ":api" is the tag I'm referring to.

```
describe 'Oh Title: Oh after title', :api, :data_key => "Oh my meta_data", :feature => "Oh my feature" do
    it 'oh my explanation' :data_key=> 'oh my meta_data' do |e|
    #blah blah#
    end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "tag"?

Comment: A tag is used for grouping your spec examples or the it statements so you can invoke it from the rspec CLI to run those or not. 

If you tag your specs, you can run like this `rspec file_path --tag :suite1, :suite2`

See documentation for more info. https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/command-line/tag-option

Comment: Thanks! I've never used that feature of rspec before. I'll take a stab at a way you can extract all the tags below.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is like 2 years late, but I am in the same spot you were in. Here is what I did.

***custom rspec formatter***

```
# spec/support/formatters/ci_rspec_run_files.rb
module Formatters
  class CiRspecRunFiles
    RSpec::Core::Formatters.register self, :example_started

    def initialize(output)
      @output = output
    end

    def example_started(notification)
      @output << "#{notification.example.id}\n"
    end
  end
end
```

***run***

```
 $ rspec --dry-run --tag ci:flakey --require ./spec/support/formatters/ci_rspec_run_files.rb -f Formatters::CiRspecRunFiles --out tmp/flakey_specs.txt
```

***result***

```
$ cat tmp/flakey_specs.txt 
./spec/models/flakey_spec.rb[1:3:6:4:1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're following the hash-rocket syntax listed in the rspec docs, something like this might work:

`grep -ri "it \"" * | grep "=>" | awk -F'=>' '{print $1}' | awk '{print $NF}' | uniq`

Breaking it down:

- `grep -ri "it \"" *` will extract all the lines containing `it "`
- `grep "=>"` will filter to only the tagged tests
- `awk -F'=>' '{print $1}'` will extract everything before the hash-rocket
- `awk '{print $NF}'` will extract just the tag
- `uniq` will only print unique tags

Comment: I'm looking more for ruby way instead of OS limited alternative. In fact, i'm running on Windows while writing these code. 

Though your solution looks interesting in terms of parsing simply by strings. I updated my question to include more info if there's a way to parse ruby codes in elegant way.

Comment: Short of writing your own parser, I think text search will be your best option. You can install all of the tools I mentioned on Windows using Cygwin (https://www.cygwin.com/).